# How to create a web based file manager that can read across different platforms?

Tags: php

I would like to try creating a PHP web file manager that could read on my machines. As I have a couple of PC and laptops, and I would like to create a central storage to store my files, documents, etc. Hence, I would like to create a web based file manager that can fulfill my need. I know there are a handful of free and opensource web file manager out there, but I would like to create my own so that I can tweak accordingly.

Hence I have some questions regarding how can I go about creating a file manager for such a purpose:

1) As I have both mac and win machines, how can my file manager be able to access the different platforms, and reading shared or portable drives as well?

2) I have done up to generating the files/folders:

```
// declare the folder
$directory = "./";

// prepare to read directory contents
$dir = @opendir($directory);

// loop through the items
while ($file = readdir($dir))
{
    // check if it is a dir
    if (is_dir($file))
    {
        echo "dir: $file <br />";   
    } else {

        echo "file: $file <br />";  
    }

}

closedir($dir);
```

How do I create the links for these files etc?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
How do I create the links for these files etc?
```

If the files are under the web root you can directly link to them but you can't directly link to just any file on the PC through the web. That would bring all sort of security problems.

You could instead link to a PHP script that would implement some form of access control to the file. To send a file from a PHP script set the appropriate mime-type using the `header()` function and send the file using the `readfile()` function.

There is an incredible amount of details involved in implementing a portable general purpose file manager such as how to handle Unix symbolic links or Windows drive letters. Too much to cover in a single Stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

There are not actual differences in the PHP file/directory functions across plattforms. `readdir` would do fine.

However I would recommend `Horde VFS` for the ambitious. http://pear.php.net/package/VFS/redirected (on PEAR, but also look for the Horde project).

It provides different backends with a unified API. It allows browsing remote files (FTP or SSH) and local stuff. It could also allow for virtual backends, like e.g. database browsing. I'm not sure if it does much, but if there are discrepancies it should also hide away differences between Mac and Win filesystems.

As for the links, simply output them as `echo "<a href='view.php?fn=$fn'>$fn</a>"` and take care to add some logic to the view script. In particular security precautions so it cannot read outside of the document_root.